# Required clock and weather web part for SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, web-part, error

I have deployed clock and weather web part in one of my SharePoint 2010 Site .And it is showing error for which I am unable to reach out to know about error details.So I am seeking for clock and weather web part.Can any one help me in providing the webpart

Comment: You are going to need to re-phrase the question.  Everyone here would encourage you to become a part of the community but there are a few rules to follow when posting. You will need to be specific in your question, and it should be a problem specific with SharePoint.  Tags are used to help target your help, using those improperly will decrease your results (tagging all the SharePoint versions in this case, was not appropriate) I would take a look at the Help section here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: shooting in the dark, but I guess the problem is that the web part code is running on the server and the server web appplication user doesn't has access to internet